# Assign values to a group of variables using recursion in C#?

Tags: c#, recursion, variable-assignment

How can I assign values to a group of variables using recursion in C#?

I can easily do it with a simple procedure, but I have no idea how to do it using recursion.

```
public void Assign()
{
Console.Write("Name: ");
Name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("e-mail: ");
Email = Console.ReadLine();

Console.Write("Phone Number: ");
Phone = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not following the question... Why would you want to use recursion for this?

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, then tag it accordingly and read how to post homework questions: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Comment: This is not a recursive operation.  Using recursion for this is a poor use of recursion.  If this is homework, naturally you "must" do the assignment.  But understand that such an assignment isn't teaching you anything...

Comment: @David it will teach him recursion.

Comment: @stefan: It may teach him vaguely how to use it.  It won't teach him _when_ or _why_ to use it.  I can show someone how to use a hammer by pounding a wood screw into concrete, but it doesn't really teach them anything.

Comment: @David Well you dont have to be able to design an house to be able to master a hammer as a carpenter. But if someone asks you to hit a nail with a hammer you should be able to do it.

Comment: @stefan: If the worker has that kind of structure where they are given specific instructions, that's one thing.  In software, it's a rare (and often not good) thing.  Teaching someone how to perform some task without teaching the concepts around that task risks giving that person a (to continue the analogy, sort of) "golden hammer."  It's important that a developer learn how to use recursion, yes.  But if he ends up using it in all the wrong places, what good was performed?  What was taught?  Tools are useless without knowing how and when to apply them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use recursion, you've got to have some sort of local context that's sufficient to accomplish whatever work you're going to do in your function, and you've got to know when / where to stop (and start popping your stack).

Your example looks like (if anything at all) a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems like homework because textbooks usually use this kind of horrible questions to teach recursion.

```
namespace Homework
{
    class Recursion
    {
        static string[] nameList = new string[5];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AssignNames(0);
            Console.WriteLine("The names are:");
            foreach(string name in nameList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        static void AssignNames(int index)
        {
            if (index == nameList.Length) return;
            Console.Write("Enter name #{0}: ", index + 1);
            nameList[index] = Console.ReadLine();
            AssignNames(index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```